# Marker interface - what's a practical code example of 'communicating a semantic constraint/guarantee that doesn't otherwise change the API

Tags: object-oriented-design, interfaces

Let's start with a loose definition of 'marker interface' (please correct me or dispute this if you disagree):

> If applied to a type, a marker interface *doesn't provide any contract
>   of methods to implement for that type*. A marker interface gives
>   semantic meaning.

So, OK, that's fine. However giving something a meaning has to ultimately have a practical consumption or usage elsewhere to be of benefit, right? So we may have two types that are different, but that are (for example) types related to 'scheduled tasks' in a system, so we may 'decorate' them both with an 'IAmTask' interface.

OK, so how do we then put that to practical use? I've read that:

> One of the benefits of a marker interface is to 'communicate a
>   semantic constraint/guarantee that doesn't otherwise change the API'.

OK, well a marker interface isn't defining a contract for methods that must be present on the type, so what's a practical example in code of how a semantic constraint/guarantee can be ultimately be returned to the user and consumed in a way that tightens up the intended guarantee to the consumer, without enforcing methods on the API? There must be a way to do this, otherwise we're simply declaring an essentially useless meaning.

Comment: How about `java.util.RandomAccess` which guarantees that indexed access to a list is efficient? All lists support indexed access, but only the ones that implement `RandomAccess` support efficient indexed access.

Comment: In C# I've mainly seen them used for generic type constraints.

Comment: I suggest reading about the design of the C++ STL. Marker interfaces are not very useful in most other languages I have worked with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since marker interfaces provide semantic meaning, they can be used like annotations to decorate a type, and you can use reflection to make decisions based on the semantics. The marker interface doesn't provide any compiler-enforceable contract.

For example, you have an interface `UserRepository`, and you have two implementations `InMemoryUserRepository` that stores users in memory and `DatabaseUserRepository` that stores users in a database.

```
interface UserRepository { def storeUser(user) }
class InMemoryUserRepository implements UserRepository { ... }
class DatabaseUserRepository implements UserRepository { ... }
```

I could introduce a marker interface to describe the semantics of the implementations. For example if I wanted to dynamically find implementations of `UserRepository` that have local semantics, I could introduce `LocalRepository` marker interface and have `InMemoryUserRepository` implement `LocalRepository`

```
interface UserRepository { def storeUser(user) }
interface LocalRepository {}
class InMemoryUserRepository implements UserRepository, LocalRepository { ... }
class DatabaseUserRepository implements UserRepository { ... }
```

The usefulness is that I can now distinguish the two repository classes from each other and decide to use the one with local semantics via reflection.

Some other examples of usages of marker interfaces:

- Big(O) complexity of implementation e.g. java.util.RandomAccess (from @immibis comment). Maybe you have a dozen different sort algorithms. You could introduce marker interfaces with worst case and best case complexities.
- Local vs. Remote. This is useful for dynamically picking a configuration for your system for testing. You could configure your dependency injection system to prefer local marked implementations when testing.
- Serialization format. I may have a couple different serializers for different file formats that all have the same interface. I could introduce a marker interface to distinguish Json serializers and XML serializers, and use runtime preferences to use the file format. Or use a marker interface to describe their size footprint and choose the best serializer for network transfer based on size.

Comment: This is good for Java. For other languages, other things might be used for the same purpose. In .net, people use attributes.